# TCPDF page size in php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Hello i'm using tcpdf to generate a file with : 5.8 cm in the width. but my code is not working :
this is the code :

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->AddPage('P', 'cm', array(5.8,7));
```

i'm not getting any errors but the size of the file is not correct

Comment: That's not the correct parameters. You can see if you hover the function inside VSCode.  AddPage(
    $orientation = '',
    $format = '',
    $keepmargins = false,
    $tocpage = false
)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$pageLayout = array($width, $height); //  or array($height, $width) 
$pdf = new TCPDF('p', 'pt', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Not working, always it  give me a page with a size not correct